# Is the maximum load of my circuit panel split evenly between the two legs?

Tags: electrical-panel

I’ve been curious about the max load of the home. I have a 200 amp service coming into my home. My question is, is it 200 amps per phase or 100 amps per phase 200 amps total? I couldn’t seem to find an answer simply my searching.

We’ve bought a few large appliances and when the ac and dryer and cooktop are on it draws close to 80 amps per phase. I started to wonder if this was approaching the limit of the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is 240V @ 200A, with a center tap neutral giving you a neutral/center return.

This is single phase with a center tap, it is not conventionally called "two phases" but rather "two poles", L1 and L2.

If you fully load it, you will pull 200A down the L1 pole and necessarily by the nature of current flowing in loops, 200A down the L2 pole.

You can pull any amount of current you please down the neutral. Since the neutral essentially breaks the big loop into two little loops, neutral only pulls differential current: if you pull 40A across L1-neutral, and 30A across L2-neutral, then neutral flows 10A.   If you draw 200A down L1 and 0A down L2, neutral carries 200A.  There is no combination of draws that can make neutral draw more than the largest pole.

If you're now thinking "I can power two 120V circuits with a common neutral", you are correct and that is called a multi-wire branch circuit.  It's fallen out of style in the age of GFCIs, because it requires GFCIs which are special.   The three conductors in a GFCI only carry two wires' worth of current, so only count as 2 wires for thermal calculations.

Answer (score 2):

"Per phase"?

You don't have multiple phases. You have single phase power.

It is delivered over two line conductors.  The phase is split by a third neutral conductor.  Thus to be more specific than single phase, you have 'split phase' power.

Most electrical services are good for 370A.

To put it simply, your 200 main breaker will cut power to BOTH lines if the current on EITHER exceeds 200A.

240v appliance loads like your examples, place the same load on both lines.

Answer (score 1):

I see a form of this question come up quite a bit. The problem is that you cannot explore whether or not a dwelling service is large enough or OK with just partial information.

You must follow the scope of NEC Article 220 Branch Circuit, Feeder and Service Calculations. You simply can't add up all of your breaker sizes and come up with a service size. We need to know the **connected load** and then we can calculate the **demand load.** Believe it or not a dwelling unit has more calculations to determine the correct service size than any other type of construction. Simply because it has so much diversification.

I would suggest to have competent master electrician or engineer do a survey and do a true calculated load on your dwelling before deciding on increasing your service size. It could save you a lot of money in the end.